# How can I change a website text using chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to change some text on a website. When I try to use innerText, nothing changes. This is the HTML of the text I want to change: `<div class="styles__tokenBalanceText___2eYY7-camelCase">742</div>`

Here is my manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "js": ["Content.js"]

        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

And here is my Content.js:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('<div class="styles__tokenBalanceText___2eYY7-camelCase">742</div>')
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerText = "123";

}
```

Comment: Use `getElementsByClassName('styles__tokenBalanceText___2eYY7-camelCase')`

Comment: I tried doing that. How should I put it in? I have it like this: const elements = getElementsByClassName('styles__tokenBalanceText___2eYY7-camelCase')

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Tamper Monkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey-beta/gcalenpjmijncebpfijmoaglllgpjagf?hl=en-GB) to run custom JavaScript on any specific website or page.

You just need to write the JavaScript code to achieve what you desire.

Comment: I want to make my own extension. Is there any other way?